# Why does Dagger not allow multiple qualifier annotations per element?

Tags: dagger

Say I have two services `AService` and `BService`, both of which require an api key.

So in my modules, I can't do something like:

```
@Provides @Singleton @A @ApiKey String provideAKey() { return "a"; }
@Provides @Singleton @B @ApiKey String provideBKey() { return "b"; }
```

(Dagger would complain with "Only one qualifier annotation is allowed per element").
Instead what I have to do, is define two separate qualifiers for each combination: `@ApiKeyA` and `@ApiKeyB`.

For a service with multiple dependencies, (think network client, request headers, etc.) it gets cumbersome to define these qualifiers for each combination, rather than simply combine different annotations.

Is there a reason why this explicitly disallowed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's to simplify Dagger's implementation, and to make it faster.

Answer (score 2):

Please see [this issue](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/201):
**JSR330 forbids to have have multiple qualifier annotations.**

For more detail, [this discussion](https://code.google.com/p/atinject/issues/detail?id=2) might be helpful.

Comment: When reading that discussion (read the last few comments) it doesn't seem like it forbids this at all, it just discourages use of multiple qualifiers if you want your `@Inject` code to be portable across injectors, or "injector-independent" as it is worded.